# Error in loading Rcpp/RcppArmadillo packages in Microsoft Open R

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I have installed Microsoft Open R in my Windows 10 laptop for better performance. I am trying to use RcppArmadillo package. The package is installed properly but when I try to load it throws the following error.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppArmadillo’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
 number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Please help with the problem.

Is there any alternate way to directly link the Intel MKL libraries with RcppArmadillo in Windows 10?

Comment: It does that upon just loading the package, i.e. when you type library(RcppArmadillo)? Also, on a more general note: Do you already have code that you would like to run faster, or is this just in preparation for a project?

Comment: Yes. install.packages(Rcpp)/install.packages(RcppArmadillo) both works fine but library(Rcpp)/library(RcppArmadillo) fails. I have a code written in Rcpp where I have used modules from the arma namespace. In [this link](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) it is mentioned that RcppArma can use the Intel MKL library when it is installed in the system. I have installed the MKL libraries in my Win10 but arma is not linking to that by default.

Comment: I must add that when I use the CRAN R, it successfully loads RcppArmadillo/rcpp without any problem. But the operations are not multi-threaded in that case.

Comment: Did you install the packages from source? Did you use a binary package?

Comment: I downloaded and installed Microsoft Open R from [this link](https://mran.microsoft.com/open) and then installed packages using the `install.packages` command. R successfully downloads and installs the package but throws error when I try to load it.

Comment: Ok, so I got my Windows 8 laptop, installed MRO 3.5.2, install.packages("RcppArmadillo"); library(RcppArmadillo), and .... it loads just fine. Then I also tried installing from source instead of binaries, works fine as well. So I guess we need more information to figure out why you have trouble with it.

Comment: Sounds like to you have some incompatible package versions installed. Have you tried runnning update.packages(ask=FALSE) ?